# the same php script executing , different memory required

Tags: php, memory

When i running the following php script to do some statistics in my local machine, 
it works well with `init_set('memory_limit', 100M)`,

however, when i executing the same php script in another web server, 
dealing with the same files(i am sure about this), 
it doesn't work.

I change the memory_limit to 1000M ,it still doesn't work, giving exception : "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1048576000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)". Finally i change to `init_set('memory_limit', 1300M)`, it works!

The php versions in the two mahchine are the same as :

```
PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2012 02:18:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
```

The following is the main script:

```
     protected function _insertTable($logType, $conf, $logFileName) {


        $logPath = $this->_getLogDirPath($logType, $conf) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $logFileName;
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($logPath);
        if ( !fileContent ) return;

        $fields = array_keys($conf['fields']);

        $dao = new dao\StatLogDao($this->_entities[$logType]);

        $lines = explode("\n", $fileContent);
$fileContent = null;
        unset($fileContent);
        foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
            $line = trim($line);
            if ( !$line ) continue;

            $lineData = explode($conf['glue'], $line);
            if ( !$lineData[0] ) continue;

            $entity = $this->_getEntity($logType);
            foreach ($fields as $k => $f) {
                $entity->$f = $lineData[$k];
            }

            try {
              $dao->replace($entity, $fields);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            }
$entity = null;
            unset($entity);
$line = null;

            unset($line);
        }
$lines = null;
        unset($lines);
$dao = null;
        unset($dao);
    }
```

I'm totally confused, it seems 'unset' won't free enough memory, plz help me out. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have different modules installed...

A lot of more things can cause your script to crash (is seems like a endless loop):

- different user rights for the webserver executing the script
- different PHP.ini settings for access of remote servers (safe_mode...)
- The file you want to access has different read rights
- Different MySQL Server version
- Different MySQL user / table / ... rights

I'm pretty sure the error you are receiving is because your script goes wrong and not because of different memory usage. You also should check if the allowed memory size `memory_limit` is really editable via `ini_set()`. Check it with `echo ini_get('memory_limit');` on both machines after you try to set it.

To be really sure that both of the servers are "same" dump the output of `phpinfo();` into two files and do a `diff` on them! Only the server names, unique ids and some dates should be different...

Comment: Thanks for you answer,but, 1: the script is executing through crontab, should not be problems about rights, even the mysql 2.the mysql version is both 'Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.21, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1'  3.according to the error message "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1048576000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)", ini_set() works, anyway the script works as expected when memory size is more bigger.  4. the main difference between the two php setting is configuring about memcached, will that matter?

Comment: As long as you run both scripts with cron it's ok. Be careful when you run PHP with cron, it then uses an other PHP.ini than the one used for Apache! Disable Memcache for testing.